# Sephardic Sefer Torah Case

Tags: sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, sefer-torah

When did the Minhag of Sephardim using an upright standing Torah case begin? From the gemara in Megila 32a it's pretty clear that in the times of Chazal this was not the prevalent custom.

So to clarify, I am not asking why they do this or if this was done in Chazal's times, but **when** it began.

Comment: [Your previous question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/88991/sephardic-sefer-torah-case-why?rq=1) on this topic was marked as a duplicate of [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/59709/why-do-most-ashkenazim-read-the-torah-flatly-on-a-table-while-many-sefardim-read) and [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11397/sefer-torah-enclosures). If you're now specifically asking about historical-time-of-origin, or something else specific that wasn't covered by those, could you edit your question to make that clearer?

Comment: The duplicate question also asks that, I think: "What is the **origin** and **reason** for these differences?" (emphasis mine).  "Origin" seems to be "when", "reason" seems to be "why".  Although I would understand if someone would disagree with me.

Comment: I find your inference interesting, as from the fact that what we call Hagbah Chazarah called Gelilah I had always assumed the exact opposite. I do question the inference, though, as I see nothing on that daf which indicates one way or the other - the way Sefardic Torahs are constructed those Halachos would apply as well.