# Mezuzah scroll upside-down on the door. Is the mitzva being fulfilled?

Tags: halacha, mitzvah, mezuzah

I observe that a mezuzah is attached to the door with the top of the mezuzah directed to the top of the door.

I am looking for sources to answer this question:

If a  mezuzah were (accidentally) attached with the top of the mezuzah facing down, has the mitzvah been fulfilled? Would a new brocho be required when putting it back the right way up?

Related: [Is there any restriction on what constitutes a mezuzah case?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8714/is-there-any-restriction-on-what-constitutes-a-mezuzah-case/8727#8727)

Comment: http://www.hashkafah.com/index.php?/topic/61296-upside-down-mezuzah/

Comment: https://www.breslev.co.il/html/its_all_in_the_mezuzah.aspx?id=126&language=english

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/RBSMezuzahDoctor/photos/a.252675655153612.1073741828.249593715461806/257230571364787/?type=3

Comment: Related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/23272/759 https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/83951/759

Comment: כל המצות כולן אין אדם יוצא בהן אלא דרך גדילתן

Answer (score 3):

The Da'as Kedoshim 32/23, also quoted by the Mikdash M'at YD 289/30 rule that it is Pasul. This is the way the B'aer Moshe 6/6/15  and Chovas Ha'dor 9/7 rule as well.

There is an opposing opinion in the Mezuzas Besecha, however it does not seem to be accepted. [See בירור הלכה חלק ו עמוד תסב - תסג]

[image]

Comment: The *Da'as Kedoshim* doesn't rule that it's *pasul*. He suggests it might be *pasul* (and even that his wording isn't so clear what he's talking about).

Comment: @Ploni - The Mikdash M'at just quotes the part where he says "אינו יצא ידי חובתו", so he understood that this is the Daas Kedoshim's ruling. This may just be the Daas Kedoshim's style, to write י"ל, similar to the Pri Megadim where he is quoted many times as paskening, while he writes י"ל or וצ"ע.